# How to fix duplicate row in a multiple query join?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.

```
|-----------------|
| user_id |  Name |
|-----------------|
|   1     | Raj   |
|-----------------|
|   2     | Khaj  |
|-----------------|
|   3     |Khujli |
|-----------------|

|--------------------------------------|
|  post_id |  Title   |  Desc          |
|--------------------------------------|
|     1    |  test1   | hello          |
|--------------------------------------|
|     2    |  test 2  |  Hello World   |
|--------------------------------------|

|--------------------------------------------------|
|  comment_id |  post_id   | user_id   |  comment  |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|     1       |     1      |     1     | Nice      |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|     2       |     2      |     1     | Bad Thing |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|     3       |     2      |     2     |  Hulla    |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|     4       |     1      |     A     |  Lol      |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|     5       |     2      |     A     |   Arse    |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|     6       |     1      |     3     |   Nice    |
|--------------------------------------------------|
```

Now I am using a query :

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_comment, tbl_post, tbl_user
WHERE tbl_post.post_id = tbl_comment.post_id 
    AND tbl_post.post_id = '$post_id' 
    AND (tbl_user.user_id = tbl_comment.user_id 
          OR (tbl_comment.user_id = 'A' 
                 AND tbl_post.post_id = '$post_id'))
```

The `user_id = 'A'` means admin, but it's not listed in the `tbl_user` table. It's only mentioned as `'A'` in the tbl_comment table.

With the above query, I am getting two rows for one comment made on a specific post by `user_id = 'A'`.

**How can I solve this?** See the image, two rows are having same values. I want unique rows, not duplicate rows.

[image]

Comment: Is not clear exactly what you want to select; Want to select only comments from users ( not Admin ) ? or comments from Admin ( not users ) or ... ?, show your correct result in an example result table

Comment: @Mahmood_M.... Let me upload an image. That will help you to understand.

Comment: @Mahmood_M.... uploaded an image.. It will help you to understand.

Comment: I advice to use the "JOIN ON" syntax for joining tables - it's much more readable and easier to troubleshoot/fix.

Comment: Yeah, the Join should definitely be used... especially since the user table should be joined via outer join since id 'A' is not found in the table.

Comment: The Join should definitely be used. The user table should be joined via outer join since id 'A' is not found in the table. I suggest to explicitely select the columns, since several coulmns exist ambigiously. Should be something like the following (not sure if 100% mySql compatible): `SELECT tp.post_id, tp.Title, tp.Desc,
       tc.comment_id, tc.user_id, tu.Name, tc.comment
FROM tbl_post tp
  JOIN tbl_comment tc ON tc.post_id = tp.post_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_user tu ON tu.user_id = tp.user_id
WHERE tp.post_id = '$post_id'
  AND (tc.user_id = tbl_user.user_id OR tc.user_id = 'A')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (*not tested*)

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_comment
INNER JOIN tbl_post ON tbl_post.post_id = tbl_comment.post_id  
LEFT JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_user.user_id = tbl_comment.user_id
WHERE tbl_comment.post_id = '$post_id'
```

I strongly advise to use `JOIN ON` clause for joining tables - much more readable and easier to troubleshoot fix.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplicates because in the second part of the `WHERE` clause you do not put any restriction on the *tbl_user* table. So for every record in the *tbl_user* table you get a repetition in your output when the comment's user ID is *"A"*.

I would also suggest you use ANSI syntax where it concerns joining tables, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM       tbl_comment
INNER JOIN tbl_post
        ON tbl_post.post_id = tbl_comment.post_id
LEFT JOIN  tbl_user
        ON tbl_user.user_id = tbl_comment.user_id
WHERE      tbl_post.post_id = '$post_id' 
       AND (tbl_user.user_id IS NOT NULL OR tbl_comment.user_id = 'A')
```

The last line in the `WHERE` clause is optional, but might be necessary if there is the slightest chance that you have invalid user ID values in your comments table. Depending on your expectations, you might not want these records to be output.